# how to return double from double plus double?

Tags: c#

I hava 2 Double variables, and when I sum them it return me int variable.
but I want it return Double too.
What should I do?
Thank you!

**example:**

```
double d = 4.0;
double Myd = 4.0; 

Console.WriteLine ( d+Myd ); // it returns me 8 but I want 8.0 .
```

Comment: It's still a double. When you do a `Console.WriteLine()` I'm pretty sure it calls the parameterless `ToString()` by default, so you can override that by doing `Console.WriteLine ( (d+Myd).ToString("#.#") );` or whatever format you want from either the [Standard Numeric Format Strings](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dwhawy9k(v=vs.110).aspx) or [Custom ones](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0c899ak8(v=vs.110).aspx).

Comment: a double with no decimal will return an INT only i suppose when you do Console.WriteLine

Answer (score 2):

The value 8 and 8.0 are the same. If you want decimals shown in your results, use a converter like N2 for fixed with 2 SigDig after the decimal.

```
Console.WriteLine((d+Myd).ToString("N2"));
```

Answer (score 0):

Shannon is corret. it is returning a double, but because it is all 0's after the decimal it cuts it off. if you were to do 8.5 + 8 it would return 16.5. If you require one decimal, just use an N1.